# index was not created even indicated in datastore-index.xml

Tags: java, google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore

My app id is gusclabs.

Index entry in datastore-index.xml:

```
<datastore-index kind="ItemGroupOptionalQuantities" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="quantityFrom" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

Error in appspot-log:

```
Type 'com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:

    <datastore-index kind="ItemGroupOptionalQuantities" ancestor="true" source="manual">
        <property name="quantityFrom" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>
```

I updated the entities after deploy the app in a new version.

When I use a query using quantityFrom to order, I have this error.

```
--- start query ----

Query query = new Query("ItemGroupOptionalQuantities");
query.setAncestor(ancestorKey);
query.addSort("quantityFrom", Query.SortDirection.ASCENDING)

PreparedQuery preparedQuery = datastore.prepare(query);

FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(10);

QueryResultList<Entity> entities = preparedQuery.asQueryResultList(fetchOptions);

--- end query ---
```

Comment: Can you provide the query that you are running? It is possible that the wrong index is being recommended.

Comment: I provided the query Patrick Costello. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just update the app then you will have to wait a few minutes for these indexes to be built. From the dashboard of your app if you visit the **Datastore Indexes** pages you should be able to see what kind of indexes you have and in what state they are.

Comment: Hi Lipis, Thanks for help. I saw the 'Datastore Indexes on dashboard. All other indexes are ok, but this was not created. There is nothing about it.

Comment: If the index you wanted is not shown in the Datastore Indexes page, you may not have uploaded them correctly. Not sure if this was just a typo, but did you mean datastore-indexes.xml, not datastore-index.xml? Can you make sure the file is in the right place (/war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated), then redeploy or run appcfg.sh update_indexes

Comment: Lipis, was a typo, the correct is datastore-indexes.xml. I'm using Eclipse. In the deploy log console, it reports index file uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The right place for the datastore-indexes.xml file is "/war/WEB-INF", not "/war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated"

Thanks Patrick and Lipis.